# How to get previous day's records in MongodDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I am using MongoDB which has a time field in milliseconds. I am trying to get all the records for previous day.
So far I have searched for solutions which show how to get the records for previous 24 hrs. But I need records for previous day only. Please help to write this query.
So something like this

```
createdTime: {
     $lt: new Date().getTime(),
     $gt: new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
},
```

But like I explained this is not what I want.

Comment: Mongo version you are looking for ?

Comment: @Gibbs Should be 4.2.3

Comment: For clarity, please define "previous day"?  Time is not absolute and depends on a user's time zone, unless we use UTC standard.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Yes I meant UTC, the given answer should work. Thanks.

Comment: @doctorsherlock thanks, however some may find timezone useful, I've included that in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the UNIX timestamps for start and end of previous day this way.
NOTE - start and end in UTC time

```js
var start = new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)-1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var end = new Date().setUTCHours(23,59,59,999)-1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
console.log(start)
console.log(end)


console.log(new Date(start).toUTCString())
console.log(new Date(end).toUTCString())
```

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have to work with date/time arithmetic then I recommend [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library:

```
createdTime: {
   $lt: moment().endOf('day').subtract(1, 'day').toDate(),
   $gte: moment().startOf('day').subtract(1, 'day').toDate()
},
```

Alternative libraries are [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) and [day.js](https://day.js.org/en/)

Answer (score 1):

We would assume "the previous day" is a 24 hour period starting at the beginning of the day before today. The easiest way to do this is use time based on UTC and add a timezone offset (if needed).

```js
const timeZoneOffset = -5;

createdTime: {
     $gt: new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0)-1000 * 60 * 60 * (24 + timeZoneOffset),
     $lt: new Date().setUTCHours(23,59,59,999)-1000 * 60 * 60 * (24 + timeZoneOffset)

},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
date ; //# => today date
        
var yesterdayDate =  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
        
createdTime: {
    $lt: date,
    $gt: yesterdayDate,
}
```

Comment: this doesn't take hours into consideration

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.